# Export each slide of Powerpoint to a separate pdf file

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I need to generate for each slide of my presentation a pdf file.

I'm using the following code:

```
ActivePresentation.ExportAsFixedFormat ActivePresentation.Path & "\" & ActivePresentation.Name & ".pdf", ppFixedFormatTypePDF, ppFixedFormatIntentPrint
```

This code works fine, but it exports all the slides into a unique pdf file.

Comment: Look into the `PrintRange` and `RangeType` parameters for `ExportAsFixedFormat`: they should allow you to specify which slide(s) get exported.

Comment: Thank you Tim, that's right! PrintRange

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do that:
Below code will create pdf with adding the slide number at end of current folder, file name.

```
Sub ExportSlidesToIndividualPDF()
Dim oPPT As Presentation, oSlide As Slide
Dim sPath As String, sExt As String

Set oPPT = ActivePresentation
sPath = oPPT.FullName & "_Slide_"
sExt = ".pdf"

For Each oSlide In oPPT.Slides
    i = oSlide.SlideNumber
    oSlide.Select
    oPPT.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Path:=sPath & i & sExt, _
        FixedFormatType:=ppFixedFormatTypePDF, _
        RangeType:=ppPrintSelection
Next
Set oPPT = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: I get the error
Run Time Error -2147467259 (80004005)':
Presentation (unknown member): The slides you ahve sleected to print no longer exist. Please make another selection.

Comment: Seems like I found a fix
When in Normal view, before the oSlide.Select statement, adding
the line
ActiveWindow.Panes(1).Activate

seems to solve the problem.

Comment: Another option without altering the code is moving around the slides in PowerPoint before running the macro, btw works great!

Answer (score 2):

For me, the the accepted answer doesn't work. Also tried the fix suggested in the comment. Probably because I'm on Mac or sth.

I found [this alternative question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38430284/powerpoint-vba-export-certain-slide-to-pdf) which I tweaked to save each slide separately:

```
Sub each_slide_to_separate_pdf()

  'Hide all slides
  For i = 1 To ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
     ActivePresentation.Slides(i).SlideShowTransition.Hidden = msoTrue
  Next i

  'display each slide and save
  For i = 1 To ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
    'display current slide
    ActivePresentation.Slides(i).SlideShowTransition.Hidden = msoFalse

    'Save location
    Dim filePath As String
    filePath = "/Users/username/Documents/vba_folder" & i & "slide.pdf"
    ActivePresentation.SaveAs filePath, ppSaveAsPDF
    
    'hide the just saved slide
    ActivePresentation.Slides(i).SlideShowTransition.Hidden = msoTrue
  Next i

 'Show all slides again
 For i = 1 To ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
    ActivePresentation.Slides(i).SlideShowTransition.Hidden = msoFalse
 Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub ExportSlidesToIndividualPDF()
Dim oPPT As Presentation, oSlide As Slide
Dim sPath As String, sExt As String
Dim dlgOpen As FileDialog
Set oPPT = ActivePresentation

timestamp = Now()
sExt = ".pdf"

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
If .Show = -1 Then ' if OK is pressed
sPath = .SelectedItems(1)

With dlgOpen

For Each oSlide In oPPT.Slides
    i = oSlide.SlideNumber
    oSlide.Select
    oPPT.ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Path:=sPath & "\" & Format(timestamp, "yyyymmdd") & "_" & "Slide#" & i & sExt, _
    FixedFormatType:=ppFixedFormatTypePDF, _
    RangeType:=ppPrintSelection
Next

End With
End If

End With
Set oPPT = Nothing
End Sub
```

I added an OpenFileDialogPicker, so you can choose the wishen location by yourself

Answer (score -2):

I discovered a fast / easy way to save individual slides in a ppt presentation as separate pdf files...nothing fancy...just a few steps...
(1) right-click on the slide (as it appears in the left-hand column), select COPY
(2) Left-Click on your bottom left Start button and open the PowerPoint program anew to a blank page
(3) Right-Click in that blank doc and hit Paste (you may have an extra blank page at the top, just right-click and Cut it to get rid of it)
(4) File / Save As / (select) PDF
REPEAT the steps for each slide

Comment: It really doesn't answer the question. I assume, that @RenanSantos wanted to do it programmatically instead of manually converting all slides.